# Receive LG Simplink signals with PC

Tags: windows, lg, hdmi

Is it possible to receive LG simplink signals on PC?

I have an LG TV connected to PC with HDMI, and I want to manage jetaudio with the remote controller of the TV.

I think the TV behaves like a "simplink server" and sends the button press events to the connected devices, so I can handle the button press events with the PC too. But this is just a theory, I haven't found anything yet about simplink in google. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it using one of these: http://www.pulse-eight.com/store/products/104-usb-hdmi-cec-adapter.aspx

So far it understands the main direction keys and the media (play, pause etc) keys.

Comment: Thanks, one step to the right direction. :-) My goals are to turn on TV by windows start automatically, and choose display settings from windows. (input label, display mode, sound volume, etc...)

Comment: It should be doable eventually but you might end up having to do a little configuring / coding. Simplink is LG's messy implementation of HDMI-CEC (there are various names for it depending on brand) and the adaptor uses that and libcec to control the TV (or any other device). http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/

Comment: I have a new monitor for a while and I created a DLNA server, so the TV is for movie and music now, btw. thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is much cheaper to buy a usb remote control (about 3€ on ebay), use only the usb infrared receiver and map your tv control buttons.
You will also get more keys from your remote, since simplink uses only a limited number of keys. Just check which of your remote keys do nothing when you are on pc mode.